# Python - Implementing leapfrog integration for nonlinear spring force, overflow encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, physics, differential-equations, nonlinear-equation

I'm trying to deal with a trivial SHM equation which has a non linear term alpha included to the spring force.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrrDP.png)

So far, I have the following code for a leapfrog integration, which I attempted to solve using:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNlrU.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/85BKE.png)
Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

k      = 1.0 # Spring constant
m      = 1.0 # Mass
cycles = 2.0 # No. of periods to integrate over
alpha  = 0.5 # Nonlinear Parameter
x0     = 1.0 # Initial displacement
v0     = 0.0 # Initial velocity

def leapfrog( steps ):
    """Solve the nonlinear oscillator equation for several 
    oscillation cycles"""
    omega = (k/m)**0.5
    delta = 2.0*cycles*numpy.pi/omega/steps
    x     = numpy.empty( steps+1 )
    v     = numpy.empty( steps+1 )
    t     = numpy.empty( steps+1 )
    t[0]  = 0.0
    x[0]  = x0
    v[0]  = v0 + 0.5*delta*x[0]*(omega**2*(1+alpha*x[0])*x[0])
    for i in range(steps):
        t[i+1] = t[i] + delta
        x[i+1] = x[i] + delta*v[i]
        v[i+1] = v[i] - delta*(omega**2*(1+alpha*x[i+1])*x[i+1])
return t, x, v

def manufactured_solution(t, i):
    omega = numpy.sqrt(k/m)
    M = alpha*omega**2*x0**2*numpy.cos(omega*t[i])**2
    x_exact = x0*numpy.cos(omega*t[i]) + M/omega**2
return x_exact

def l2_error_norm( t , x ):
"""Calculate the L2 relative error norm."""
    steps  = len( x ) - 1
    omega  = (k/m)**0.5
    l2_err = 0.0
    l2     = 0.0
    for i in range(steps):
        x_exact = manufactured_solution(t, i)
        l2_err += (x[i] - x_exact)**2.0
        l2     += x[i]**2.0
    return (l2_err/l2)**0.5

n = 14
steps = 8                                                    
delta    = numpy.empty( n )
l2_error = numpy.empty( n )

for i in range(0,n):
    t, x, v     = leapfrog( steps )
    delta[i]    = (k/m)**0.5*(t[1]-t[0])
    l2_error[i] = l2_error_norm( t , x )
    plt.plot( t , x )
    # plt.show()
    steps *= 2

# Switch to a new plotting window, and plot the L2 error norm,
# with guidelines for first, second, and third order accuracy.
plt.figure()
plt.loglog( delta , l2_error , 'o' )
plt.loglog( delta , l2_error[0]*(delta/delta[0])**1.0 )
plt.loglog( delta , l2_error[0]*(delta/delta[0])**2.0 )
plt.loglog( delta , l2_error[0]*(delta/delta[0])**3.0 )
plt.show()
```

If I try and attempt to solve for this it has these errors:

```
nhm.py:38: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
v[i+1] = v[i] - delta*(omega**2*(1+alpha*x[i+1])*x[i+1])
nhm.py:49: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
l2_err += (x[i] - x_exact)**2.0
nhm.py:50: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
l2     += x[i]**2.0
nhm.py:51: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in 
double_scalars return (l2_err/l2)**0.5
```

Any helpful insight is appreciated

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not attach screenshots of your code and add it as text instead, as that makes it much easier for us to help you [among other reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Please provide more debugging information, at what iteration does this happen, what is the state, can you get plots of the trajectory,...